# Pyspark - Load trained model word2vec

Tags: python, load, pyspark, gensim, word2vec

I want to use word2vec with PySpark to process some data.
I was previously using Google trained model `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` with `gensim` in Python.

Is there a way I can load this bin file with `mllib.word2vec` ?
Or does it make sense to export the data as a dictionary from Python `{word : [vector]}` (or `.csv` file) and then load it in `PySpark`?

Thanks

Comment: I have already loaded pyspark models in the .parquet format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Binary import is supported in Spark 3.x](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html):

```
spark.read.format("binaryFile").option("pathGlobFilter", "*.png").load("/path/to/data")
```

However, this would require processing the binary data. Hence a `gensim` [export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471037/save-results-of-word2vec-model-query-in-a-csv-file) is rather recommended:

```
# Save gensim model
filename = "stored_model.csv" 
trained_model.save(filename)
```

Then [load the model](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html) in pyspark:

```
df = spark.read.load("stored_model.csv",
                     format="csv", 
                     sep=";", 
                     inferSchema="true", 
                     header="true")
```